# How to avoid the "no permission to perform operation "Make attribute" UCM" error message?

Tags: clearcase

I am receiving the below error when I am trying to edit the value of `Proj_Mgr` in UCM.

Please advise

```
no permission to perform operation "Make attribute" UCM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must see an error like:

```
No permission to perform Make Attribute. 
Must be one of: member of object group, object owner, VOB owner, member of admin group
```

So check your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable, and compare it to the groups of the vob, or the associated pvob (in UCM).
You can see those by describing the vob:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\myVob
```

As a possible cause, check out the IBM technote
"[Problems that occur if the ClearCase Administrator group owns the VOB or VOB objects](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264867)":

> When a VOB or objects contained within a VOB (elements and metadata) are owned by the ClearCase Administrators group, this will most certainly result in permissions errors whenever an operation is performed against that object by a non-Admin user.
>
> Since the administrators group by default has access to all ClearCase objects, it is not necessary to explicitly add that group and should be avoided.

You can see a concrete scenario where that error pops up in:
"[Error setting the recommended baselines for this stream](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21128173)" (for a Stream though. In your case, you shouldn't have to reprotect the Vob, but rather make sure you have the right identity/group).

Answer (score 1):

I used this command to solve this issue (a protection issue as described above):

```
ct protect -chgrp ccuser project
```